# Django: Internal Server Error: /media/images/c5.png

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with displaying the uploaded image from the admin panel, which does not appear on the site.
The following error that the server returns:

```
Internal Server Error: /media/images/c5.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 69, in process_request
    if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 321, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 223, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 230, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 104, in get_callable
    (lookup_view, mod_name))
ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import django.views,static.serve. Parent module django.views,static does not exist.
```

I would add that it was only following inclusion in the file urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG :
     urlpatterns + = patterns ('',
     ( r ' ^ media / ( ? P < path> . *) $ ', ' django.views , static.serve ', {' document_root ' : settings.MEDIA_ROOT } )
     )
```

I view the page correctly , but no picture.
My page is on the local server

Can anyone help.
Thank you in advance.

the urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^article/',include('articles.urls')),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'projekt.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^projekt/', include('projekt.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += patterns('',
     (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views,static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
     )
```

settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/marcingrzywacz/Desktop/polano2/cms/projekt/media/' #pelna sciezka musi byc na localu

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And the last I add on site:

```
 <img alt="" src="{{ article.image.url }}">
```

Comment: Add a `!` in front of `[image][1]` to make image render properly in the question first.

Comment: @Narendra: you could've made that (suggested) edit yourself, of course.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error, instead of providing a non-readable image.

Comment: Did you import the `django.views.static` module?

Comment: Why is there a comma in `' ' django.views , static.serve '`? That should be `'django.views.static.serve'` (spaces not required/recommended either).

Comment: @Evert Edits must be at least 6 characters. I suggested a single `!` only.

Comment: django.views is correct as You written. Just when I copy here interceded spaces.

Comment: in terminal i get "GET /media/images/c5.png HTTP/1.1" 500

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Evert for pointing me to the error. Should be `'django.views.static.serve',` instead `'django.views,static.serve',`